# Scaling image to 420px using Image Styles

Tags: 7, media

I am using Image Styles to get the following effect:

width: 420px.
height: no greater than 240px.
Maintain aspect ratio.

To do this I have used Sale width 420 then crop 420x240, although any images which are less than 240 (height) get enlarged back to 240 using a black background.

I have also tried scale 420 then scale and crop 420x240 as this should only cut it off if it is larger, but it doesn't work, and stretches the image horizontally for any images with a height less than 240.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Simply require a minimum width in the image field's config form.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [ImageCache actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) module, you will get some extra image effects. One is "Define Canvas." What you probably want to do is use "Scale" to make it 420px wide, and then use "Define Canvas" to put this on a canvas with the correct dimensions.

Comment: I have to define a HEX value, and then images which are less than 240px high will be placed onto a background. I want it so there is no background! How do I do this?

Comment: No background is no HEX value. But transparent backgrounds only work with PNG and GIFs I think.